# Order of operations for SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server-ce

Suppose I have this statement:

```
SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE a = 1 or b = 2 and c = 3
```

Does that mean: (a = 1) OR (b = 2 AND c = 3) or does it mean (a = 1 or b = 2) AND c = 3? Can I change what it means, i.e. execute the OR before the AND or is this not possible?

Comment: `(a = 1) OR (b = 2 AND c = 3)`

Comment: Order of operations doesn't really follow this.  It will return anything where a=1 and c=3 or anything where b=2 so it's more of an 

`(a=1 and c=3) or b=2`

Comment: sorry I know it's not the best example, my real world issue is pretty massive and too difficult to sum up in a compact way, I just needed to know how to lump up operations together

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From [Technet](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173435):

> When more than one logical operator is used in a statement, AND
>   operators are evaluated first. You can change the order of evaluation
>   by using parentheses.

So yes, it means `(a = 1) OR (b = 2 AND c = 3)`.

You can force the behavior you want by writing the parentheses as you did above: `(a = 1 OR b = 2) AND c = 3`